# is it possible to search for user names with solr?

Tags: search

I'm trying to allow users to be able to search and find their friends on my site.  I'm not sure how to do this. Could someone guild me please?

I read that solr is not able to search usernames so instead you must convert their profile to nodes..I installed Content Profile, and migrated but still no luck.  Not sure how to do this.

please help!

Thanks!

Comment: r u using D6 or D7?

Comment: Default search comes with user search. You can't use that?

Comment: I'm using D6..default search doesn't seem to work, when I'm admin I can see it but not as a normal user.  I want something similar to facebook's search where it autocompletes users and then takes you directly to their profile page(i'm using content profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the Content Profile module, as long as anonymous users have access to view the profile nodes, the content should be able to be indexed by Solr.  You can use the [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) and [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) modules to ensure that the username is set as the Content Profile node's title. You might want to set the field bias for the title to a higher value so more importance is placed on it when ranking search results.

Normal users probably can't see the core User search because they don't have the "access user profiles" permission.  If they are granted that permissions they should be able to use the core User search.